# Two part of different font size text bottom aligned

Tags: html, css

Pls see: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/TkfSx/1/)

What I want to do is: horizontally, put the first sentence on the left, and put the other one right.  Vertically, I want to align them to the bottom.  The two sentences are not the same font size.  I searched this topic for a while and think `display:table-cell` should work, but you see, the two sentences are not bottom aligned.  Any help will be appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div class="di_header">
    <div class="di_h_en"><p>I'm left</p></div>
    <div class="di_h_cn"><p>I'm right</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.di_header{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.di_h_en{
    width:30%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    text-align:left;
    border:solid 1px red;
}

.di_h_cn{
    width:70%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align:right;
    border:solid 1px red;
}

.di_h_en p{
    font-size:32px;
}

.di_h_cn p{
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: Can you remove `P` tag. That will solve the problem.

Comment: for seo consideration, I need it be there.  Thanx for your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318221/remove-the-space-in-element-p/22318500#22318500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/TkfSx/3/)

```
*{
margin:0px !important;
}
```

You need to remove the auto generated margins. i've specified the height of your table cells to see the effect of bottom alignment

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin and you will get your desired output

```
.di_h_cn p {
   font-size: 24px;
   margin: 0;
}
```

as `p` tag has these two rules to add margin

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this only to solve your issue

```
p{margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write HTML you should know that most of HTML tags takes default margin and padding. To remove those margin and padding you should use one of the following techniques:

- Use [**CSS Reset**](http://www.cssreset.com/) [**recommended**]
- Use following CSS

  `body, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h5, h6, form, input, blockqoute { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      line-height: normal; 
  }`

By using one the above techniques your HTML elements behaves same in cross browsers.