# Remove the space in Element p

Tags: html, css

Fist of all, pls see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317521/two-part-of-different-font-size-text-bottom-aligned) and the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/TkfSx/8/)

You can see even set the `margin:0px;` to the element, there's still a space between the text and the

element border.  It's a problem when I put Chinese and English text in one line, because the space for English and Chinese is not the same.  Anybody know how to solve this?

I know it's not a big issue, but want to make it perfect to look, also want to learn more about css and html.  Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the height's lines of paragraphs with the `line-height` property:

```css
* {
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}

.di_header{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.di_h_en{
    width:30%;
    height:100px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    text-align:left;
    border:solid 1px red;
}

.di_h_cn{
    width:70%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align:right;
    border:solid 1px red;
}


.di_h_en p{
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:30px;
    border:dashed 1px black;
}

.di_h_cn p{
 font-size:24px;
    border:dashed 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="di_header">
    <div class="di_h_en"><p>I'm left</p></div>
    <div class="di_h_cn"><p>I'm chinese 我是中文</p></div>
</div>
```

Here, I put a `line-height` a little smaller, so it reduces the margin with border. Play with the `30px` value to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep `font-size` same for both or like mentioned above use `line-height` and play with it until you are satisfied.

demo:

[`Jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/TkfSx/9/)

or

[`Jsfiddle2`](http://jsfiddle.net/TkfSx/14/)

Comment: Bro, instead of giving the direct link here post your code. so in future if the links are dead, this answer still valuable.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening becuase both `<p>` contains different `font-size`.. you can fixed them by using `line-height` property.

Add the `line-height` in the CSS. you use 32px font-size on another `p`  element.

```
.di_h_cn p{
    font-size:24px;
    border:dashed 1px black;
    line-height:38px; /* Add this line*/
}
```

Here is a DEmo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/TkfSx/13/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `margin-bottom:0` for `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the margin at the top of text inside the cell. If this is what you want then remove the `height:100px` from the `.di_h_en{your-styles-here}`